# how can I get the index of a character in a given concurrence which is repeated several times in a TEXT line using SHELL (BASH) script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a Text string like below

```
"/path/to/log/file/LOG_FILE.log.2013-10-02-15:2013-10-02 15:46:57.809 INFO  - TTT005|Receive|0000293|N~0000284~YOS~TTT005~  ~000~YC~|YOS     TYOS-YCUPDT1-H                  20131002154657669284YCARR TTT005   Y0TD04 |1|0150520106050|001|051052020603|003|015030010101502702060510520101|000||000||                                                               "
```

Here `"|"` is repeated several times within the string and I need to get the index of 4th occurrence of `"|"` character using shell-script (BASH) command. I tried to find a way using grep command's options.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to get the fourth "field" delimited by |, then you can just use `cut`.

Comment: Do you really need the index, or is that just a step towards extracting a substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` can print the byte-offset; when used with `-o` it prints the byte-offset of the matching part.

```
$ string="/path/to/log/file/LOG_FILE.log.2013-10-02-15:2013-10-02 15:46:57.809 INFO  - TTT005|Receive|0000293|N~0000284~YOS~TTT005~  ~000~YC~|YOS     TYOS-YCUPDT1-H                  20131002154657669284YCARR TTT005   Y0TD04 |1|0150520106050|001|051052020603|003|015030010101502702060510520101|000||000||"
$ grep -ob "[^|]*" <<< "${string}" | sed '5!d' | cut -d: -f1
132
```

Alternatively, without using `grep`:

```
$ newstring=$(echo "${string}" | cut -d\| -f5-)
$ echo $(( ${#string} - ${#newstring} ))
132
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F '|' '{print index($0, $5)-1}' file
```

This will print character position of fourth pipe in the file.

Comment: Nice.  Didn't know that.